# How to check if something is currently being dragged (from a different origin)?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

The [HTML Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) will fire `dragstart`/`dragend` events on the item being dragged.

This makes it easy to update a `dragInProgress` variable, which can be used to check if a drag is in progress.

However, this approach does not work if the user initiated the drag in a different browser window, because `dragstart/dragend` will fire in a different browser window.

A workaround would be to store `dragInProgress` in `localStorage`, but I can't use that approach because I need it to work even if something is being dragged in from a different origin (e.g. if an image or link is being dragged from a web page from a different web site).

How can I check if the user is currently dragging something across the page, if it has an external origin?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your idea 100% but here is an example of how you can drag something over the page and get something from the [DataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) object when the dragged item is dropped.

The dragged item can be anything dragable item from the OS or anything form a web page in another browser window.

```js
document.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('.over').classList.add('show');
  document.querySelector('.drop').classList.remove('show');
});

document.addEventListener('drop', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  [...e.dataTransfer.items].forEach(item => {
    console.log(`kind = ${item.kind}, type = ${item.type}`, e.dataTransfer.getData(item.type));
  });
});
```

```css
.page {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: Azure;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.drop {
  display: none;
}

.over {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="page"><span class="drop show">Drop here</span><span class="over">Something is being dragged</span></div>
```

Comment: Hi, your code will notice when the user is dragging something over the page. However, I need to additionally know if the user has released the mouse and is no longer dragging something over the page (which will happen if they either perform a drop, or if they abort the drag). Ideally, a global variable (in the window object) called dragIsInProgress would be set, so I can query it elsewhere. The reason this is useful to me is because there are parts of my web page that will automatically refresh, and I want to prevent things from refreshing if the user is currently trying to drag something